# Select columns that contain only values from an external list

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter a data frame so that I only keep columns that have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or NA in them.

```
x = data.frame(col1 = c("a" , "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
           col2 = c(12, 45, 235, 2134, NA, 1), 
           col3 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, NA), 
           col4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA), 
           col5 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

With this example data, I would like to return x with only col 3 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  select(where(function(x) all(x %in% c(1:5, NA))))

  col3 col4
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    1    4
5    2    5
6   NA   NA
```

Or using a formula:

```
x %>%
  select(where(~ all(.x %in% c(1:5, NA))))
```

Since the discussion just heated up on this, in case you would like to know how R interprets formulas created by `~` pronounced `twiddle`, just wrap it inside `purrr::as_mapper`. This is a function R calls behind the scene when you use this syntax for an anonymous function:

```
as_mapper(~ all(.x %in% c(1:5, NA)))

<lambda>
function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
all(.x %in% c(1:5, NA))
attr(,"class")
[1] "rlang_lambda_function" "function"
```

Here `.x` argument is equivalent to the first argument of our anonymous function.

Comment: Hey my dear friend! Long time no see. :-) Btw.: That's basically not a formula but the tidyverse style of an anonymous function. ;-)

Comment: Hiii Martin how are you? Have been busy with school and learning new stuff. I don't think i could get back here again like before but sometimes how knows. It is in fact `purrr-style lambda` but in documentation calls it a formula. But I always appreciate your helpful hints. How's everything with you?

Comment: I'm fine. Yes, SO takes a lot of time but every now and then it's worth a visit. But school/university clearly has a higher priority. :-)

Comment: Just chiming in to say it is a 1-sided formula that is converted to a function via `rlang::as_function()`.

Comment: It's always nice to practice your newly-acquired skills here but sometimes you tend to get so much time on them as the competition is always tempting. But these days you need to master many skills while you don't have enough time so I am trying to be more focused on my own affairs :)

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Yes exactly you are right.